# How to pop out warning?

Tags: java

```
 if(btnSubmit.equals("Submit")){
     if(checkdata()== true){
     InsertData();
     url = "/mimy/Dbtable.jsp";
         }
 else{
      out.println("Fill up all the field");
      url = "/mimy/Register.jsp";
 }
 }
```

The following codes are the options I have tried to ensure that the user fill in all the fields of the form. If the user does not fill in any of the field,a pop up statement should be displayed. But the code above is not working. How can I work this out?

Comment: Define "not working".  I don't even see a complete code fragment in regards to a pop-up.

Comment: I tried the out.println but it was not displayed. So I need a better option.

Comment: @Makoto: why do you think that this is JavaScript? It sure looks like Java to me. But I have to admit that the question is not clear at all, it forces us to guess, and I sure hope that the original poster improves it soon.

Comment: Perhaps it's JSP, which is a very real possibility.  I'll rollback what I did and beg for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

out.println won't pop up anything.  Write Javascript code to pop up message.

e.g. `alert("fill up all fields ");` in javascript

Answer (score 0):

This worries me:

```
if(btnSubmit.equals("Submit")){
```

Is your btnSubmit really a String? Somehow I doubt it. Somehow I think that it's a *button* of some kind.